# GROUP_CONCAT and INNER JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a problem with getting data. I would like to find all courses, which contain the flag in where clause and get all flags course it contains.

Records for the **course** table:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Spring   |
| 2  | Hibernate|
| 3  | C#       |
+----+----------+
```

Records for the **course_flags** table:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |course_id |  flag_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  |     1    |     1    |
| 2  |     1    |     2    |
| 3  |     2    |     1    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Records for the **flag** table:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | promocja   |
| 2  |last minute |
+----+------------+
```

**My query**

```
SELECT course.id, course.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Flag.id SEPARATOR ',') as flags
FROM course
INNER JOIN course_flags ON 
    course.id = course_flags.course_id
INNER JOIN flag ON 
    flag.id = course_flags.flag_id
WHERE flag.name LIKE 'promocja'
GROUP BY Course.id
```

Unfortunately my database engine returned records with one flag in **flags** column:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |   name   |   flags  |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Spring   |     1    |
| 2  | Hibernate|     1    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I had hoped to get this result:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |   name   |   flags  |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Spring   |   1,2    |
| 2  | Hibernate|    1     |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Question how do I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note:  Your `GROUP BY` clause is more correctly `GROUP BY course.id, course.name`.  As written your query will not work on most RDBMSs because it is ambiguous.  MySQL just chooses to ignore that fact and guess and what you mean.  You'll be fine as long as `course.id` is a primary key, but it's still better to specify the fields like you're supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause restricts records *prior* to grouping; whereas the `HAVING` clause restricts results *after* grouping:

```
SELECT   course.id, course.name, GROUP_CONCAT(Flag.id) flags
FROM     course
    JOIN course_flags ON course_flags.course_id = course.id
    JOIN flag ON flag.id = course_flags.flag_id
GROUP BY Course.id
HAVING   SUM(flag.name = 'promocja')
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12a15/1/0).

Comment: While this is a valid solution, depending on the cardinality of the flag data, it may make more sense to pre-filter the course id's using a sub-select.  The OP should test both ways to see which is more efficient for his use cases.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Agreed. I posted this answer more by way of demonstrating the problematic effect of `WHILE` vs `HAVING` rather than to address any particular (unmentioned) performance concerns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with simply using joins like that is that your `WHERE` clause will reduce the flags available to the result set.  What you really need to do is use a subselect to first determine the id's that have this flag, then using that set of id's, determine the flag for each of those id's.  that may look like this:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS id,
    c.name AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(cf.flag_id) AS flags
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN course_flag AS cf
    ON c.id = cf.course_id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT cf2.course_id AS id
    FROM course_flags AS cf2
    INNER JOIN flag AS f
    WHERE f.name = ?) AS ids
    ON c.id = ids.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Where `?` is the flag name you are querying for.  Note I also used `=` here in the `WHERE` clause instead of `LIKE` since you weren't even using `LIKE` functionality (you had no wildcard).