# Manipulation AND OR in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a problem with getting data. I would like to find all courses, which contain specified flags. How to write SQL code to find courses that flags the same type was OR condition and for other type was between AND condition.

Records for the **course** table:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  Spring  |
| 2  | Hibernate|
| 3  |  LATEX   |
+----+----------+
```

Records for the **course_flags** table:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |course_id |  flag_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  |     1    |     1    |
| 2  |     1    |     2    |
| 3  |     1    |     3    |
| 4  |     2    |     2    |
| 5  |     2    |     3    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Records for the **flag** table:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |     name    |     type    |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 1  |  promotion  |   NORMAL    |
| 2  | last minute |   NORMAL    |
| 3  |   Samsung   |ACCREDITATION|
| 4  |    Nokia    |ACCREDITATION|
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

**My query**

```
 SELECT course.id,
      course.course_name,
      GROUP_CONCAT(Flags.id SEPARATOR ',') as flags
 FROM course
 INNER JOIN course_flags ON 
    course.id = course_flags.course_id
 INNER JOIN flags ON 
    flags.id = course_flags.flags_id
 AND ((flags.id =1 OR flags.id =2) AND flags.id = 3)
 GROUP BY course.id, course.course_name
```

Unfortunately my database engine returned zero records.

I had hoped to get this result:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |   name   |   flags  |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Spring   |  1,2,3   |
| 2  | Hibernate|   2,3    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Question how do I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GROUP\_CONCAT and INNER JOIN with WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235013/group-concat-and-inner-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: A flag cannot be 1 or 2 and at the same time be 3. So that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is different

Comment: The problem isn't materially any different, nor is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already answered to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22235013), a `JOIN` predicate (as with the `WHERE` clause) restricts records *prior* to grouping; whereas the `HAVING` clause restricts results *after* grouping:

```
SELECT   course.id, course.name, GROUP_CONCAT(flags.id) flags
FROM     course
    JOIN course_flags ON course_flags.course_id = course.id
    JOIN flags ON flags.id = course_flags.flag_id
GROUP BY course.id
HAVING   SUM(flags.id IN (1,2)) AND SUM(flags.id = 3)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06fbd/3/0).